Migrating from Debian 11 to 12, the sudo apt dist-upgrade finishes on a message: 'unknown directive "set_by_lua"' from nginx
I am upgrading a VM at work, from Debian 11 to 12.
I succeed up to the sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, where it fails on:
Setting up nginx (1.22.1-9) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
× nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-06-11 11:50:59 CEST; 9ms ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 31990 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 3ms

Jun 11 11:50:59 development systemd[1]: Starting nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jun 11 11:50:59 development nginx[31990]: 2024/06/11 11:50:59 [emerg] 31990#31990: unknown directive "set_by_lua" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:17
Jun 11 11:50:59 development nginx[31990]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

What's that 'unknown directive "set_by_lua"', and why does it cause a trouble here and now?

nginx modules were split out between Debian 11 and Debian 12. set_by_lua is handled by the Lua module, which is now in the libnginx-mod-http-lua package; so
sudo apt install libnginx-mod-http-lua

is necessary for your nginx configuration to work.
This should have been handled for you during the upgrade, but without knowing exactly which nginx packages were installed before the upgrade I can’t determine what went wrong.
